# MySQL Syntax Error, Unrecognized keyword null

Tags: mysql, sql

MySqli/phpmyadmin query not working - unrecognized keyword 'NULL'

I use

```
PHP - mysqli
MySQL + phpMyAdmin
```

**Sql** :

```
update User set name = null;
```

**Error** :

> Unrecognized keyword null

thank for any help !

Comment: Works for me. http://rextester.com/YSTH80658  (note I used table muser as it wouldn't let me create user) perhaps you need `user` in backticks...  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html it is a reserved/keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User is a [reserved/keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) word in mySQL.  offset it in backticks.

```
update `User` set name = null;
```

http://rextester.com/YSTH80658 using muser.... I don't think they will let me create a table called user or drop it.

Comment: thank you ! actually that was a error from the phpMyAdmin editor, the query work :)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
UPDATE `User`
SET `name` = NULL;
```

see more information about UPDATE and SET [here](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp)

But maybe your column doesn´t allow **NULL** values

Comment: Thought it could be a syntax error maybe, and I gave him a hint "But maybe your column doesn´t allow NULL values"

Comment: That would give a completely different error message.

Comment: k, then i dont know

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_column = NULL
WHERE  some_id = 1;
```

or:

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = NULL;
```