# What is the value of a valid empty blob on mysql?

Tags: mysql, blob

Let's just say you want to insert or update a row on table named **table_a**.

**table_a** has a *blob* column named **column_a**. In **column_a** you just want to insert a valid and minimal empty value by deliberately passing a value.

Is that possible in MySQL? If so, what is the value of a valid empty blob?

Comment: Just `NULL` should work?

Comment: @Terry I tried `... SET column_a=NULL` but did not seem to work. It said `Unrecognized keyword. (near "NULL" at position 66)`

Comment: That's probably because you are using reserved keywords in your query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390539/mysql-syntax-error-unrecognized-keyword-null. You can [set up an SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to show us a basic, proof-of-concept example.

Comment: Note that `Unrecognized keyword. (near "NULL" at position 66)` is **not** an error that came from a MySQL Server. This particular error seems to be a defect in whatever query tool you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A NULL should work for populating a BLOB column.

**Illustration:**

```
-- Create a table with BLOB column
CREATE TABLE table_a (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
column_a BLOB
);

-- Populate a row with BLOB column as NULL
INSERT INTO table_a values(1,NULL);

-- Check data in table
select * from table_a;
+----+----------+
| id | column_a |
+----+----------+
|  1 | NULL     |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: If you fill the blob with null value, your datagridview will error when has image with a null value. I assumse blob for store image binary

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` value may be what you are looking for. Assume that your table has columns `id` and `data`. If `data` has no default value, then you can execute `insert into table_a (?, ?) VALUES (1, NULL)`. The corresponding record will then have an `id` of `1` and a `data` equals to `NULL`.

The other solution is to define your column with a default value set to `NULL`. Then, the above request is equivalent to `insert into table_a (?) VALUES (1)`.

Extern reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: I tried the same procedure for an update query but it did not work. `update table_a set column_a=NULL`

Comment: What is the structure of your table ? Is `column_a` allowing null values ? If not, you need to change the constraints of the column with the `ALTER` expression (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alter-table.aspx)

Comment: it does not allow null values

Comment: So that's probably why you cannot set `NULL` as a value. You should then use
`ALTER TABLE table_a
CHANGE COLUMN column_a column_a BLOB;`

or 

`ALTER TABLE table_a ALTER column_a SET DEFAULT NULL;`

so that it has a default value set to `NULL`.

Comment: this is the reason why I thought there must be a valid empty blob value instead of `NULL`. I should not alter the column

Comment: I see. What I do not understand is why you consider the `NULL` value as an "invalid" value. What kind of data does your column store? If it is an object `Object` you may store the instances of `Object()` (default constructor, or something equivalent) as valid empty blob values. 

However, I would recommend to allow `NULL` since this is semantically what you want I think.

Comment: the blobs are kinda intended for files/images

Comment: Then you should allow `NULL` to denote `no file` or `no images`. I think that it is fundamentally false to assume that `NULL` cannot describe this situation. However, if you do not have the possibility to change at all, then just put an empty string instead (`not null` does not mean that a false-equivalent value cannot be used, but stands for “not having a value").